# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

The code runs fine without the `@foreach` statement. When it's added I get the following error:

```
Undefined variable: articles (View: C:\laravel\laravel\resources\views\about.blade.php)
$articles is undefined.
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $articles }} with {{ $articles ?? '' }}
```

When I add the `?? ''` it creates the error:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Here is the complete code for the more daring:
https://github.com/matthoek/Articles

This is my view:

```
        <? if (is_array($articles) || is_object($articles)) ?>
            {
                @foreach ($articles ?? '' as $article)
                {
                    <li class = "first">
                        <h3>{{ $article->title}}</h3>
                        <p><a href="#">{{ $article->excerpt }}</a></p>          
                    </li>
                @endforeach
                }           
            }
        </ul>
```

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Article;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = App/Article::latest()->get();
        //$articles = Review::all();
        //$article = Review::all();

        return view('articles.index',['articles'=>$articles]);
        //return view('articles.index', ['articles' => $articles]);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $article = App/Article::find($id);

        //return view('articles.show', ['article' => $article]);
        return view('articles.show')->with('article');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('articles.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        //validation

        //clean up
        $article = new Article();
        $article->title = request('title');
        $article->excerpt = request('excerpt');
        $article->body = request('body');
        $article->save();

        return redirect('/articles');
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        return view('articles.edit');
    }
}
```

This is the section of my routes file web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () 
{

    Route::get('/about', function () {
        $article = App\Article::latest()->get();
        return view('about', compact('about', 'articles'));
        //return $article;
    });
}
```

I have changed the section of the routes file to the following but it did not seem to work.

```
 return view('about')->with(['article'=> $article]);
```

I have made sure the following was in my `app/Http/Kernel.php` in `middlewareGroups` property for `web`
`\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,`

I have changed the foreach loop to an each loop and I get the same error on the line:

```
<h3>{{article->title}}</h3>
```

Let me know if I should post more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes:

```php
    Route::get('/about', function () {
        $articles = App\Article::latest()->get();
        return view('about', compact('about', 'articles'));
    });
```

It will return a collection, you can just loop it:

```php
             <ul>
                @foreach ($articles as $article)
                <li class = "first">
                   <h3>{{ $article->title}}</h3>
                   <p><a href="#">{{ $article->excerpt }}</a></p>          
                </li>
                @endforeach
              </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your view

```
 <? if (is_array($articles) || is_object($articles)) ?>
        {
            @foreach($articles as $article)

                <li class = "first">
                    <h3>{{ $article->title}}</h3>
                    <p><a href="#">{{ $article->excerpt }}</a></p>          
                </li>
            @endforeach   
        }
    </ul>
```

the error is in you foreach loop: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php